# play-Framework: Passing renderArgs into Javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, playframework

I'm putting some `renderArgs` into the template to be loaded. These `renderArgs` are then sent to a function on page load like so..

```
jsFunc(${value0},${value1});
```

However, they're not being interpreted correctly. If we assume the variable `${value0}` represents a String which is equal to `ThisIsTheValue`. The Javascript will throw the following error in Chromes console...

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ThisIsTheValue is not defined
```

Why is this happening? How can I resolve it?

Comment: If it's meant to be a javascript string, then it has to be quoted: `"ThisIsTheValue"`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put your args in `""` to mark thema as Strings in JavaScript. Otherwise JavaScript interpret them as undefined variables and throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

try someting like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var x = ${value0};
  jsFunc(x);

</script>
```